# Perfect Numbers - On Mersenne and Euler Primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, open-problems

Hi, I apologize if there is already an (obvious) answer to my question, but please bear with me for the moment as I find it hard to see a good way to answer this question:

In the same way that the Mersenne primes uniquely determine the even perfect numbers (i.e. in the "bijective" sense), do the Euler primes likewise uniquely determine the odd perfect numbers?

That is, while an Euler prime obviously maps to a single odd perfect number, it is not obvious to me that an odd perfect number could only map to a single Euler prime.

This is because:

(1)  In the most general case, it is not known whether squares are friendly or solitary.

(2)  It is not even known if the smallest possible Euler prime 5 does divide an odd perfect number.

(3)  It is conceivable that two distinct numbers $P$ and $Q$ which satisfy a particular number-theoretic equation do not necessarily have to satisfy $\gcd(P, Q) = 1$.

I hope you guys can help me out on this one.  Establishing this very last gap will provide a proof for the implication:

Assuming Sorli's Conjecture for OPNs is true, then there are no OPNs.

Comment: "an Euler prime obviously maps to a single odd perfect number"

completely not obvious for me! I know many Euler primes, but no odd perfect numbers.

Comment: Euler showed that an odd perfect number must be of the form $N = p^{4\lambda+1} Q^2$.  In this context, $p$ is the 'Euler prime'.

Comment: @Fedor, I was operating (of course) under the assumption that there is at least one OPN, and that the abundancy index $I(n) = \sigma_{1}(n)$ is A function.  That being said, thanks!

@Stopple, Euler did show the general form that an OPN can take (which we usually call the Eulerian form).  What is not obvious to me is:  Why can't two distinct OPNs (if there are at least two) share the same Euler prime?  (I do apologize, though, if you were directing your comment to Fedor instead...)

Comment: @Arnie, so I think the 3rd paragraph in your question is backward. Each OPN (if there are any) corresponds to exactly one Euler prime, while it is not obvious (to either of us) that a given prime can be the Euler prime of at most one OPN. 

Comment: @Gerry - exactly.  And I am sure you do remember this discussion thread, where we tried to work on proving that squares are solitary?  http://sci.tech-archive.net/pdf/Archive/sci.math/2006-05/msg05551.pdf

Comment: @Gerry - assume there are at least two distinct OPNs which share the same Euler prime. Then you will have to solve the problem in my previous comment if you want a "Tour de Force". Thus, the motivation for my question. I am trying to understand why the Euler primes are in one-to-one correspondence with the OPNs in the same way that the Mersenne primes are in one-to-one correspondence with the EPNs.

Comment: I am of course, still working with the Eulerian form for an OPN.  I find it hard, however, to justify (using my approach) that distinct Euler primes determine distinct OPNs, and vice-versa.

Comment: I don't get it - p is the only prime factor with an odd exponent. 

Comment: @Franz, I am assuming existence of at least two OPNs.  I want to show that if $N_1$ and $N_2$ are distinct OPNs, then they cannot share the same Euler prime (which, of course, gives some evidence for the discussion on solitary squares).  But I do not want to go that far!  In other words, is it "provable" (i.e. not in the sense of being merely "obvious") that every rational point on the hyperbola $XY = 2$ with $1 < X = I(p^k) < I(m^2) = Y < 2$ corresponds to only one $N = {p^k}{m^2}$?  More details here:  http://arnienumbers.blogspot.com/2010/12/pre-final-stage-towards-elementary.html

Comment: @Arnie: I think Franz's point -- which I agree with -- is the following.  Your statement about the "correspondence" between odd perfect numbers and Euler primes seems backwards: according to Euler, every odd perfect number $N$ has a unique Euler prime -- i.e., a unique prime number $p$ with $\operatorname{ord}_p(N) \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  You are asking -- aren't you? -- whether the same prime number can be an Euler prime for more than one odd perfect number.  

Comment: Anyway, do you have any reason to think that this uniqueness statement can be proved?  If not, this seems like more than a "gap": it sounds like a very intractable problem in its own right.

Comment: @Pete, that's exactly my point.  And its intractability is related to an open problem on solitary numbers -- and I did already see that I had to hurdle that much way back in 2006.  But then again, notice that if anybody could prove that the square component of an OPN has to be solitary (which gives more evidence to the conjecture I mentioned RE: solitary squares), then that will contradict (essentially) one of Erdos's results on primitive solutions of the equation $I(a) = I(b)$.  (I will try to get hold of the URL to that paper for you in a while, I am away from home because my PC's infected.)

Comment: @Arnie: I'm afraid I don't understand why "because I want to prove that there are no odd perfect numbers" is a proof strategy for your uniqueness statement.  I didn't ask whether you thought it was true -- if there are no odd perfect numbers, it is vacuously true -- but rather why you thought it is any easier to prove than the no odd perfect numbers conjecture itself.  

Comment: @Pete:  Here is the link to Erdos's paper:  http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1959-21.pdf.  That was published in Acta Arithmetica in 1959.  And it is listed in http://upforthecount.com/math/abundance.html as a "keystone paper".  I invite you to take a look at it and see for yourself why.  =)

Comment: Please refer to a clarification I made in my latest comment below my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to get in touch with Dean Hickerson and here's what he got to say regarding the problem of determining the status of squares with respect to solitude or friendliness:

> Notice that all of the squares from $1$ to $121$ are
>   solitary (since they satisfy $gcd(n, \sigma(n)) = 1$).  (See [OEIS - A014567](http://oeis.org/A014567).)
>   Does my observation hold true in general?

No.  The smallest square for which $\gcd(n, \sigma(n))$ is not equal to $1$ is $196$:  $\gcd(196, \sigma(196)) = 7$.  (But it's easy to show that $196$ is solitary.)

In $1995$ I found a square that isn't solitary; I don't know if there are any smaller ones:  $26334^2 = 693479556 = 2^2 3^4 7^2 11^2 19^2$.  There are at least $5$ other numbers with the same abundancy index:

$$    8640 = {2^6}\cdot{3^3}\cdot{5}$$

$$    52416 = {2^6}\cdot{3^2}\cdot{7}\cdot{13}$$

$$    71814642425856 = {2^{13}}\cdot{3^4}\cdot{11^3}\cdot{31}\cdot{43}\cdot{61}$$

$$    2168446760665473024 = {2^{13}}\cdot{3^{10}}\cdot{11}\cdot{23}\cdot{43}\cdot{107}\cdot{3851}$$

$$    5321505362711814144 = {2^{13}}\cdot{3^6}\cdot{11}\cdot{23}\cdot{43}\cdot{137}\cdot{547}\cdot{1093}$$

> I had expected my conjecture to fail for even 
>   squares.  Notwithstanding, have you also found
>   any odd squares which are not solitary?

No, I haven't.  It's easy to find odd squares for which $\gcd(n, \sigma(n))$ is not equal to $1$; e.g. if  $n = {21}^2 = 441$  then $\gcd(n, \sigma(n)) = 3$.  But $441$ is solitary.

Hence, it appears that the status of odd squares is still an open problem.

Comment: An odd perfect number (OPN) $N$ given in the so-called Eulerian form $N={q^k}{n^2}$ (with $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q, n) = 1$) can only have exactly one Euler factor $q^k$.  On the other hand, assuming the existence of at least two OPNs, I am considering the problem of whether these two (distinct) OPNs can share the same Euler factor $q^k$.  Given the abundancy index constraints, we have the equations $I(q^k) = \frac{1}{I({n_1}^2)} = \frac{1}{I({n_2}^2)}$.  Thus, the related problem on the solitary status (or otherwise) of odd squares. This appears to be intractable, Pete said.

Comment: It is *trivial* to prove that the equations
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=\frac{2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})}=\frac{\sigma(N/q^k)}{q^k}$$
hold.  In particular, using a result from [Dris (2012)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html), we have
$$\frac{\sigma(N/q^k)}{q^k} \geq 3$$
so that we obtain
$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) \neq 1.$$
Thus, Greening's Theorem (a sufficient but not necessary condiiton for a number to be solitary) fails to establish the solitude of $n^2$.